# Image Type conversion with OpenCV imwrite

Tags: python, image, opencv, matplotlib

I'm calculating the DCT of a image with the following code:

```
img = cv2.imread(imgName,0)
imf = np.float32(img)
dctimg = cv2.dct(imf)
```

The problem is when saving the image with OpenCV's `imwrite` function I'm getting the desired output.

```
cv2.imwrite('output-dct.png',dctimg)
```

[image]

But while saving with matplotlib as `plt.imshow(dctimg, cmap='gray')` I get a completely black image.
[image]

I understand that OpenCV is converting it to 8bit image. So I tried to do the same using normalization

```
cv2.normalize(orgDct, dctimg,alpha=0, beta=1, 
                           norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
dctimg = np.uint8(dctimg)*255
plt.imshow(dctimg, cmap='gray')
```

But the results are not the same.
[image]
How to achieve the same effect as `imwrite` when plotting with matplotlib ?

Comment: The normalization is wrong - you set range to 0-1 and datatype CV_8U. The line after that is pointless, just directly normalize into range 0-255.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the `vmin` and `vmax` parameters of the `imshow` function. Which gives the DCT images as desired equivalent to OpenCV's `imwrite`.

So the program looks like this:

```
img = cv2.imread(imgName,0)
imf = np.float32(img)
dctimg = cv2.dct(imf)
plt.imshow(dctimg, cmap='gray', vmin = 0, vmax = 255)
```

Here is the output of the above code:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're making a mistake:

```
dctimg = np.uint8(dctimg)*255
```

should probably be

```
dctimg = np.uint8(dctimg*255)
```

because assuming the values of your dctimg are between 0.0 and 1.0, your code would have converted only the very highest values to 1, the rest to 0, and then multiplied the result with 255 – yielding 0 "almost everywhere".

Also, make sure your DCT actually yields only positive values. I don't think that's usually the case.

Comment: Yeah, that won't help, but the problem is even earlier -- `dtype=cv2.CV_8U` when normalizing into a range between 0 and 1. So it's just ones and zeros already, the cast to `np.uint8` is likely redundant.